# PHP Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/module.so

Tags: php, module, centos6

`php --version`

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/module.so' -
>
> /usr/lib64/php/modules/module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Dec 11 2013 03:29:57)
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

Answer (score 8):

1. I check all file in : /etc/php.d/
2. It was   mcrypt.ini  with this line

   > extension=module.so

but module.so not exist in /usr/lib64/php/modules/

3. I reinstalled  mcrypt with yum install mcrypt and the result I have  mcryp.so in  /usr/lib64/php/modules/
4. so now just correct the line in mcrypt.ini   and make

> extension=mcrypt.so

Now all is ok