# PHP extension CORBA client with omniORB libraries gives runtime error with "undefined symbol "

Tags: php, c++, corba, omniorb

We are trying to create a PHP extension in C++ that will operate as a CORBA client.

The server side is written in Java. Our runtime environment is CentOS 6.6.

We have used omniORB to compile the IDL and create the C++ skeleton code for the client. Our first step was to create a client program that works correctly. We then included the functionality in a PHP extension that compiles and links without any errors.

When however our extension library is installed and tested in PHP we get the following error:

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_midas.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/php_midas.so: undefined symbol: _ZTv0ortableServer11ServantBase9_downcastEv in Unknown on line 0.`

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem was to change the config.m4 file used for setting up the php extension, so that it included references to the omniORB libraries using the `PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH` macro instead of the `PHP_ADD_LIBRARY` one, although the libraries were in the default /usr/lib64 folder.

I am including the entire file as a working reference.

```
dnl PHP extension definition written in C++ that uses the omniORB libraries
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(php_midas, whether to enable midas extension, [  --enable-php-midas   Enable PHP Midas extension])

if test "$PHP_MIDAS" != "no"; then    

    dnl -- Add support for standard C++ runtime    
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH( stdc++, /usr/lib64/, PHP_MIDAS_SHARED_LIBADD)

    dnl -- Incldue the omniORB libraries
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH(omniCodeSets4, /usr/lib64/, PHP_MIDAS_SHARED_LIBADD)
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH(omniConnectionMgmt4, /usr/lib64/, PHP_MIDAS_SHARED_LIBADD)
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH(omniDynamic4, /usr/lib64/, PHP_MIDAS_SHARED_LIBADD)
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH(omniORB4, /usr/lib64/, PHP_MIDAS_SHARED_LIBADD)    
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH(omnithread, /usr/lib64/, PHP_MIDAS_SHARED_LIBADD)

    dnl -- Our extension consists of two cpp files            
    PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(php_midas, php_midas.cpp coordinatesConverterSK.cpp, $ext_shared)

    PHP_SUBST(PHP_MIDAS_SHARED_LIBADD)

    dnl -- Declare C++ extension
    PHP_REQUIRE_CXX()
fi
```

Comment: To be fair, I did tell you to check the extensions (: Anyhow im happy to hear you solved it, +1

Answer (score 0):

Altered from [Source:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654392/php-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-usr-lib64-php-modules-module-so)

There are many different reasons which could cause such a problem with the DLLs. First - **Ensure all the files are in place** - does the midas module exist there? is there a proper referance to it in the enviroment?

**Make sure the extension is set** -Make sure you have the SO module, and then that your configuration file has the SO type as the extension type, or in other words, this line exists:

```
extension=module.so
```

If this didn't help, consider dynamically checking the linker - is the error in the loading, or some of the headers didnt fit?

Let me know what happened.

**EDIT**: It seems like the error is in the loading beacuse of undefined syntax. Well then, [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/530513/php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-usr-lib64-php-modules-gd-so-undef) is a similar case I will base my answer on.

Your error means, that `ZTv0ortableServer11ServantBase9_downcastEv` symbol cannot be found in shared libraries used by the module. It is probably provided by a library which is not a defualt - not php-gd, probably omniORB.

```
readelf -s <path to SO file>
```

and

```
nm -D <path to SO file>
```

will list symbols and I'm very sure, that you won't find it there.

There's probably an unupdated library from the omniORB type interfering with the referance - for example Remi could be one. If you have it in your code, or any other one which might do this, you could reset them;

For example, if you think the remi files are interfering, you can reset them by Removing all remi packages (`rpm -qa|grep remi`), delete remi-release package and install last available php/gg/etc packages from EPEL repository (you may need to downgrade them with `rpm -Uvh package.rpm --oldversion`). Then upgrade all packages.

Some more links with similar questions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800203/php-cannot-load-shared-libraries), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329210/php5-4-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-gd-so-undefined-symbol-gdgetc), [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library),  and even [here.](http://forums.famillecollet.com/viewtopic.php?id=3110)

Let me know if this helped you.

Comment: Hello, I have verified that he file is in place and the relative reference to php.ini is correct. As far as "dynamically checking the linker", I honestly have no idea how to do it.